# How to explore specifc files with wildcards in netrw?

Tags: netrw

I would like to list files starting with `abc` in the current directory with `netrw`.
if I use `vim .` it lists all files. I also could list them using `vim -c "E"` just I don't know how to filter those which don't match `abc*`

Comment: Possibly `:help netrw-edithide`, though you have to get the pattern right. Depending on what you're doing, `netrw-mr` could be useful too.

Comment: That pattern is for hiding how to give pattern for only show files